# dnsmasq DNS cannot be reached by local devices

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, mac, dnsmasq

I am currently working on a locally hosted website running on the free version of MAMP. I wanted to assign this website a domain name, hence i came across dnsmasq. I have set up the program using https://www.stevenrombauts.be/2018/01/use-dnsmasq-instead-of-etc-hosts/

The DNS works perfect on the host device, with the weblink domain.develop directing me to my webpage. Great! But I cannot access the webpage through the address from another computer connected to my router. I can open the page using my IP address though from the other computer.

I am running Mac OS Mojave as the host and have a Foxtel Hub router (If it helps).

The dnsmasq filter is still operating through its origional port (53 I think) and is redirecting the domain name to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). As per the above tutorial, I am only sending domain.develop to dnsmasq.

What I want is for other local devices attached to my router to be able to visit the website hosted on my mac using the static DNS (domain.develop).

Many thanks,

BFB

Comment: I assume you configured the other computers to use the computer running **dnsmasq** as DNS server and that **dnsmasq** is bound to `0.0.0.0:53`, not `127.0.0.1:53` (check with `netstat -uln | grep :53`). One last problem remains: **dnsmasq** is resolving `domain.develop` to `127.0.0.1`, which every computer interprets as _"myself"_.

Comment: So do you recommend I set myself a static IP on my router and use that IP as the address to redirect my domain to? And what do you mean by configuring the other computers? I though DHCP handles all of that automatically. The command returned nothing BTW. (Yes dnsmasq was running XD)

Comment: Where is the **DHCP** server running? I suppose you didn't configure `dnsmasq` to do `DHCP` too, so probably on your router. On your router, you can configure the list of `DNS` servers, which will be sent through `DHCP`. Configure it to only send the IP of the computer running `dnsmasq` (which should be static).